# Linear convolution in R using bandSparse & matrix multiplication

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, convolution

In R I can calculate a linear convolution of a vector `y` with a convolution kernel `K` using

```
linconv = function (y,K) {   K=K/sum(K)
                             out=convolve(y, K, type="open")
                             out=head(out,-(length(out)-length(y)) )
                             return(out)
}
```

E.g. if I had a vector `y`

```
t = 1:1000
y = 10000*exp(sin(t*0.02))
```

and convolution kernel `K`

```
K = dexp(1:41, rate=1/5)
```

the linear convolution of `y` with convolution kernel `K` would be `linconv(y, K)`

Now I would like to calculate my linear convolution instead using matrix multiplication, by setting up a banded convolution matrix containing as columns time-shifted copies of my convolution kernel `K`. Ideally I would like to use `Matrix::bandSparse` to set up this banded convolution matrix. Would anyone happen to know the right syntax of `bandSparse` though to accomplish this, and obtain the same result as using the linear convolution function above, but obtained using matrix multiplication instead? Right now I did

```
linconv2 = function (y,K) {  K=K/sum(K)
                             require(Hmisc)
                             lags = 0:(N-1)
                             X = as.matrix(data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(lags, function(lag) Lag(c(K, rep(0, length(y))), shift=lag)))))
                             X[is.na(X)] = 0
                             ntoclip = (nrow(X)-length(y))/2
                             X = X[head(1:nrow(X), -(nrow(X)-length(y))),]
                             out = as.vector(y %*% X)                                 
                             return(out)
}
```

but I would like to set up the matrix `X` above instead using `Matrix::bandSparse`. Would anyone know the correct syntax to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha found the correct syntax after all:

```
linconv2 = function (y,K) {  K=K/sum(K)
                             require(Matrix)
                             X = as.matrix(bandSparse(length(y), 
                                              k = seq(-(length(K)-1),0,1), 
                                              diag = t(replicate(length(y), rev(K))), symm=FALSE))

                             out = X %*% as.matrix(y, ncol=1)
                             return(out)
}
```